# How to extract information from command prompt, working with c++?

Tags: c++, date, time, calendar, command-prompt

i wanna make a program on c++ that tells you how many days, years and months need to pass to get to a certain date. Also i wanna include how many hours and minutes need to pass.
So my problem is that i do not know how to get the current date and time to a variable from the command "time" on cmd or anyway to get the current date date and time so it will work.
I accespt the program done already so i can see it and end my doubts.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/

Answer (score 1):

1. Get input with getline()
2. Parse string to date format
3. Use some time/data library to find the difference
4. Output to console

Answer (score 0):

While this is almost certainly homework, you might find this post useful (points to the Boost library): [C++ DateTime class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267219/c-datetime-class)