# C# like DateTime in C++

Tags: c#, c++, datetime

What is the alternative for `C# DateTime` class in C++? I am looking for an underlying calender with support for incrementing hours, days or weeks. It should also support comparison of dates.

Comment: C# is based on the .NET-Framework which offers many predefined objects and UI-elements, for C++ you would need to use a library supporting this. It has no built-in calender.

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267219/c-datetime-class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ doesn't have a date/time class in the standard library. But you can use Boost -

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_tutorial

Comment: Thanks, looks like a viable alternative. BTW, how does it work? Do I need to use the dll or include the header only?

Comment: @e4e5f4 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries