# make a program use a specific date

Tags: c++

I have a program that needs to execute from a specific date.
The program is a shop of fast food. When I was doing it in Java, I used Calendar:

```
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
```

Clients make requests. After a request, I need the time to be increased in 10 mins.

```
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
```

Is there a way to do some similar in C++?

The date is: 12/20/2013 ; 23:59:59

Comment: Why do you need a class for that? If you __know__ the date, you can explicitly type it in a `std::string`...

Comment: There is support in the Boost Library, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267219/c-datetime-class

Comment: @PawełStawarz, if I do this, how can I handle 1000 of requests? Or 10000? I would have to define operations for adding time in this string.

Comment: Potential duplicate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/adding-time-to-struct-tm

Comment: By the way, in Java 8 and later, the modern approach would be: `LocalDate.of( 2013 , Month.DECEMBER , 21 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )` and compare with `isBefore` method. To add ten minutes, call `.plusMinutes( 10 )` or `.plus( Duration.ofMinutes( 10 ) )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have the structure *tm* in header ctime (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm). This allows you to create a date similiar to Java's Calendar.

To add e.g. minutes you simply do

```
dateObj->tm_min += 10
```